# How do I implement a "Does Not Contain" condition for Automation Notifications?

Tags: acumatica

In Automation Notifications (SM205040), I want to add a condition that a certain string field of the Shipment class does not contain a given substring.

Specifically, I want to generate a notification for a shipment, when the Status changes to Confirmed, but only if the Shipment ID does not start with "IP-".

There does not appear to be a "Does Not Contain" option, when defining a condition. Acumatica version is 6.10.1219.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Could you please describe more detailed what you want to achieve with examples. I think that you should be able to do that without need of `does not contain` option

Comment: Added more detail